# Discord.JS embed: User avatar in footer

Tags: javascript, php, discord.js, embed

I'm trying to port over some PHP code my friend made for a Discord bot, to DiscordJS. Here's what he wrote for an embed (in PHP):

`$embed->setFooter($message->author->username, $av = $message->user->avatar);`

I'm having trouble trying to port over the part that adds the user avatar to the footer, I can't figure out what 'AV' is and how it adds the image to the start of the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AV is the second paramter given to `$embed->setFooter)`

[TAKEN FROM DOCS]

In discord.js, there are also two paramaters `text: StringResolvable` and `iconURL: string`. `iconURL` is an optional paramater.

To port
`$embed->setFooter($message->author->username, $av = $message->user->avatar);`
just add

```
embed.setFooter(message.author.username, message.user.displayAvatarURL());
```